# How to reuse a named view with a nested nested route in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, view, vue-router, nested-routes

I have searched in lots of parts of Internet (stackoverflow,vue documentation, blogs, etc.) and I haven´t found the solution that I need. So, the issue is the following:

**routes.js**

```
 {
    path:'/',
    components:{
        allPageView:LytSPA
    },
    meta:{
        requiresAuth:true
    },
    children:[
        {
            path:'',
            name:'admin',
            components:{
                sectionView:AdminDashboard
            }
        },
        {
            name:'admin.users',
            path:'usuarios',
            components:{
                sectionView:Users
            },
            children:[
                {
                    name:'admin.users.create',
                    path:'crear', 
                    components:{
                        sectionView:UsersCreateEdit
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]}
```

So, the paths are: / , /usuarios and /usuarios/crear.

My views are: App.vue (with a named view), LytSPA.vue (with a named view), AdminDashboard.vue, Users.vue, UsersCreateEdit. So, I have 2 node views and 3 leaf views.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
<router-view name="allPageView"></router-view></template>
```

**LytSPA.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
    <header>
        <header-view></header-view>
    </header>
    <transition name="slide-left-aside">
        <aside v-show="!collapsed">
            <aside-view @collapse="collapseAside"></aside-view>
        </aside>
    </transition>
    <transition name="slide-expand-button">
        <b-button @click="collapseAside(false)" id="btnExpand" v-show="collapsed">
            <font-awesome-icon icon="chevron-right"/>
        </b-button>
    </transition>
    <section id="sectionSPA" :class="{collapsed: collapsed}">
        <breadcrumb-view></breadcrumb-view>
        <router-view name="sectionView" key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    </section>
</div></template>
```

As you can see, in **LayoutSPA.vue** I dropped my main views in the container **sectionView**, thus:

- when the path is **/** load the Dashboard view.
- when the path is **/usuarios** load the Users view.

And here comes the problem, when the path is **/usuarios/crear**, it either doesn´t load the UsersCreateEdit view or it keeps the last one (Users.vue). However, the routing is working because I put a redirect validation for unknown URLs, since the url **usuarios/crear** doesn´t change so that's work but doesn´t load the view.

I have already worked of this way with UI-Router in AngularJS and there wasn´t any problem because it works with inheritance of states, but I want to know if exists any way to do the same in Vue???

Note: I have an alternative solution but I don´t like it, because I have to put the *admin.users.create* route as a sibling of *admin.users* and it works but I need that it be nested because I need to retrieve the matched routes to build my breadcrumb and I don't want to parse the path to build it.

[image: path /usuarios/crear with incorrect view (Users)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem and I found the solution in the following post in [dev.to](https://dev.to/berniwittmann/my-approach-on-vue-router-architecture-and-nested-routes-2kmo).

If you want to show the list component and the form component in separate views. You can create a root component which wraps both the list and form:

`User.vue` (wrapper)

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

And you must have something like that in your routes.js file

```
//...omitted for brevity
const routes = [
{
    path: "/users",
    component: User,
    children: [
      { path: "/", component: ListUsers, name: "user-list" },
      { path: "new", component: FormUsers, name: "user-form" }
    ]
  }
];
//...omitted for brevity
```

If you don't want to create a new file for the root component, you can use the `render` method:

```
{
    path: "/users",
    component: {
     render(c) { // render the wrapper component
        return c("router-view");
      }
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: ListUsers
      },
      {
        path: "new",
        component: FormUsers
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I reviewed that article in [dev.to](https://dev.to/berniwittmann/my-approach-on-vue-router-architecture-and-nested-routes-2kmo) and in the **Step 4: Deep Nesting Routes** that is I was looking for, and in addition with your last comment about avoid create a new file with router-view is also helpful for me, since I think is more practical. Thank you, and I also hope (in a future) that Vue Router has a model of states inheritance in routes to do this easier.

Answer (score 0):

When you add child route `admin.users.create`, it's mean that in parent route with name `admin.users` component must contain own `<router-view>` with name `sectionView`.

You can find that picture in `vue-router` [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

```
/user/foo/profile                     /user/foo/posts
+------------------+                  +-----------------+
| User             |                  | User            |
| +--------------+ |                  | +-------------+ |
| | Profile      | |  +------------>  | | Posts       | |
| |              | |                  | |             | |
| +--------------+ |                  | +-------------+ |
+------------------+                  +-----------------+
```

The component `User` contains its own `<router-view>`, where rendering components `Profile` or `Posts`

So, add `<router-view name="sectionView"></router-view>` into component `Users`, or move route to higher level.

Comment: You mention the another alternative solution that I had thought, but if I add the `<router-view>`  in `Users.vue`, when I click on the Agregar button (Add User)  this will appear below of the users table and I don´t like that. I wanted to visualize only the UsersCreateEdit view instead of Users view, so, I guess that I have to put a `v-show="false" or v-if="false"` in Users view (to hide the users table) when I click on the Agregar button :( . Thanks anyway.